# Debug Javascript variable passing

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, loops, debugging

I have a google map that displays markers with longitude and latitude information from a web page that is parsed by the makeRequest function. At the moment markers are placed with the displayLocation call by calling makeRequest. The exact markers that I want are placed on the map. My trouble is trying to provide more details for the infoWindow of the map marker.

I do not understand the scope of the participantName variable. When I pass the participantName in through the makeRequest call I am receiving the last participantName in the array which is populated in the infoWindow of each marker.

Half of my goal is complete where each marker is unique to a participantID (long, lat). I want to loop through another array which has participant names and populate them along with each respective marker.

The output of the loop is displaying the last name in the Array while it should be displaying the value at participantNames[i] in the array corresponding to the first for loop.

```
                var participantIDs = <?php echo json_encode($participantIDs) ?>;
                var participantNames = <?php echo json_encode($participantNames)?>;

                var participantID;
                var participantName;

                for(var i = 0; i < participantIDs.length; i++)
                {
                    participantID = participantIDs[i];
                    participantName = participantNames[i];

                    makeRequest('pageWithLocationInfo.php?participantID=' + participantID , function(data) 
                    {
                        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                        {
                            displayLocation(data[i], participantName);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

              function displayLocation(location, pName) {

                var content = '<div class="infoWindow">' + '<p>' + pName + '<br/>' + 'Latitude: '  +  location.latitude
                + '<br/>' + 'Longitude: ' + location.longitude + '</p>'
                +  '</div>';

                }
```

Comment: Dynamically creating Javascript like that isn't a great idea - it'll probably be a lot easier for you to debug if you serve the data separately and then have your (static, standalone) script read the data.

Comment: I feel like I'm so close to getting my result that I am just missing a small detail. Not really understanding how I each marker is assigned participantNames[8] when I'm passing in participantNames[1],[2],[3].... Using a static string participantName = "Test" assigns all markers with the "Test" name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following and tell me what the output is. Also need to know how `makeRequest` indicates failure.

```
var participantIDs = [];
var participantNames = [];

if(participantIDs.length!==participantNames.length){
  throw new Error("participants id's and names are not the same length");
}
Promise.all(
  participantIDs.map(//map names and id's to [[id,name],[id,name]]
    function(id,index){
      return [id,participantNames[index]]
    }
  ).map(
    function(idName){//in ES7 you can use ([id,name])=>new Promise...
      return new Promise(
        function(resole,reject){
          makeRequest(//What does makeRequest return to indicate failure?
            "pageWithLocationInfo.php?participantID=" + idName[0],
            function(data){
              resolve(data);
            }
          )
        }
      ).then(
        function(response){
          var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
          data.forEach(function(location){
            displayLocation(location, idName[1]);
          })
          return [data,idName];
        }
      )
    }
  )
).then(
  function(results){
    console.log("results is:",results)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want each iteration to have a separate binding for `participantID` and `participantName`. Since `var` has function scope and is hoisted, you should use `const` or `let` instead. Or, even better, avoid `for` loops completely and use `forEach`, which does not require manual iteration and has automatic abstraction. Try something like this:

```
const participantIDs = <?php echo json_encode($participantIDs) ?>;
const participantNames = <?php echo json_encode($participantNames)?>;
participantIDs.forEach((participantID, i) => {
  const participantName = participantNames[i];
  makeRequest('pageWithLocationInfo.php?participantID=' + participantID, function(response) {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    data.forEach(item => displayLocation(item, participantName));
  });
});
```

An uglier solution would be to just use `let` in your loops, which has block-scope (easy to interact with) rather than function scope (harder to interact with):

```
var participantIDs = <?php echo json_encode($participantIDs) ?>;
var participantNames = <?php echo json_encode($participantNames)?>;
for (let i = 0; i < participantIDs.length; i++) {
  const participantID = participantIDs[i];
  const participantName = participantNames[i];
  makeRequest('pageWithLocationInfo.php?participantID=' + participantID, function(dataR) {
    const data = JSON.parse(dataR.responseText);
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      displayLocation(data[j], participantName);
    }
  });
}
```

Don't use the same iteration index variable name for both the inner and outer loop; use different names.